# Pycharm CE 2017 issue - no editor, console, tabs or windows

Tags: pycharm

Just upgraded my Pycharm from 2016 to 2017 (Mac OSX). Opened the project and...

1. Cannot see project view (although I do have project structure, top left and can navigate through the hierarchy)
2. Cannot see code editor, cannot view/edit code modules
3. Cannot see console

The environment is pretty useless. What am I missing?

Also, looking at the files/projects in Finder all 'py' files now have the xcode icon which means pycharm does not recognise the files as python...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like PyCharm Interpreter settings got wiped. So although the project retained its settings, the actual environment did not.